# pdflatex error: latex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool

Tags: errors, texlive, format-files

I'm having some problems trying to get a portable TeX Live installation working.  It started off great, but I tried to use `tlmgr` to add some packages and now whenever I run `pdflatex` I get a weird error.

Google isn't being much help - most of the discussions are about a bug in the system install for some Linux distros (which I'm not using) or they suggest I run `fmtutil --all` which completes without error but doesn't fix the problem.

I'm not sure what to try next.  This is what happens when I run pdflatex:

```
$ ./bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**t
---! ./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

There is no `pdftex.pool` file in the portable install or in my system installation (which does work.)

Any idea what the problem is or what I can try next?

Comment: One possibility is that `fmtutil` used the system installed TeX distribution binaries rather than the portable ones. There is no `pdftex.pool` file because it has been incorporated in the binaries; that's the origin of my feeling. Possibly a `PATH` problem

Answer (score 21):

Modern pdftex embeds the "pool file" in the executable, so this message means the format was created with a different executable.  Running `fmtutil --all` normally puts generated formats in `$HOME/.texlive2013/texmf-var/web2c/` and these should be used in preference to the system `texmf-var/web2c` versions. You should be able to locate the generated format and log files, e.g., using `locate pdflatex.fmt`.  This information could help pinpoint your problem.

Given the information you provide, it is impossible to say what broke.  Did you set the `PATH` in your terminal session as mentioned in the portable texlive instructions?

`fmtutil` normally puts generated formats in `$HOME/.texlive2013/texmf-var/web2c`, so breaks portability.  If you actually used `sudo fmtutil --all` then `$HOME` would be root's value, and any generated formats would not be available to other users.

You probably want to use `fmtutil-sys --all` (with the `PATH` set appropriately) to have the generated formats go into the portable texmf-var tree (e.g., are stored on the USB key with the rest of texlive).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  No, I have not set any path.  The only instructions I can find are at http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable but they don't mention anything about setting paths.  If I put the portable TeXLive's `bin/x86_64-linux/` path first, running `fmtutil --all` still doesn't work - but the output does mention /usr/share which is wrong because this is outside my portable install.  Same for `fmtutil-sys --all`.  I am not running as root.  I can't seem to find any more docs about the portable install - any pointers?

Comment: http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable has: "To run TEX using this portable installation, you need to add the appropriate binary directory to the search path during your terminal session, as usual."  For linux there is very little difference between a portable install and a normal CTAN TeX Live install, so use the normal documentation.

Comment: Any progress on this? I get this error just by running pdfjam in a SuSE 12-->13.2 installation.

Comment: I had the same problem when upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and the command `fmtutil --all` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar problem. I was able to solve it using `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` command on my Arch-linux box. The reply by @doed was helpful.

Comment: I still don't understand what this command do and why updating TeX packages (using the official TeX Live distribution updater) broke everything, but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem: at the same folder where one is running LaTeX, there was an obsolete latex.fmt file. Please, erase it.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem and running `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` did not help. I then used `locate pdflatex.fmt` to find all instances of the troublesome file. `locate` pointed me to the following locations:

```
/home/phx/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/home/phx/.texmf-var-BackUp/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
```

I then copied `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt` to `/home/phx/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`. After this everything worked out fine again.