# Latex error after ubuntu 14.04 update

Tags: format-files

I updated my operating system on my laptop from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 yesterday, and now I cannot compile my .tex files. I always get the following message.

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.
---! /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)`

I tried searching for some information and found the suggestions offered [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live_FAQ#Q:_I_just_updated_texlive_and_it_stopped_working). I tried first running

```
fmtutil --all
```

but that didn't work, so next I tried

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

but that also didn't work. I also found this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124343/pdflatex-error-latex-fmt-doesnt-match-pdftex-pool) asking essentially the same question, but the focus there seemed to be on having a "portable install." I'm not exactly sure what a portable install is, but I don't think I have that on my laptop so I don't know if the answers on that thread are of any use to me.

Comment: It might be better to remove TL (you are using 2013) and reinstall to get 2014 instead.

Comment: What is the best way to remove texlive and reinstall. The reason I ask this is that (from my perspective) the texlive files are stored in all these strange locations that I don't know of and I want to make sure I don't have any errors caused by multiple files if I update to 2014.

Comment: The thing here is that with a 'managed' TeX Live install  the problem is more one at the Ubuntu end than the TeX one ('normal' TeX tools don't apply). I'd use the Ubuntu package manager to remove anything with 'TeX Live' in the name, as suggested by @daleif, then re-install.

Comment: I haven't yet removed the old texlive install. Even if I reinstall texlive, I'm not sure I'll get the 2014 version. The one listed in the ubuntu packages is version 2013.20140215-1.

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` first? and exactly how did you list the texlive packages?

Comment: I just tried running 'apt-get update' and then 'apt-get upgrade' just now. The first command seemed to work fine, but the second generated a ton of error messages (all seemingly related to tex or texlive packages). It looks like maybe I need to do a fresh reinstall of texlive.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by re-installing TeXLive.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just removing my old texlive installation and reinstalling it fresh. Not the most elegant solution, but it seems to have worked.